# Erlang crashes (must be ejabberd): Why and how to debug the logfile?

Tags: crash, erlang, ejabberd, crash-reports

Everyday I have a new Erlang crash report on my server. As ejabberd is the only Erlang-thing I use, this must be the cause of the crash.

The logfile (`erl_crash.dump`) has almost 9,000 lines so I have no idea how to debug that. But when I searched for "ejabberd" in that logfile, there were 5 occurrences - and every single occurrence was something related to "ejabberdctl".

I'm addressing ejabberdctl via PHP script (`exec()`) to programatially create users. Could that be the cause for the crash (somehow)?

In `/var/log/ejabberd` directory, I've found some errors in `erlang.log` and `ejabberd.log`. But I don't really know how to resolve them:

```
=ERROR REPORT====
Mnesia('ejabberd@MYHOST'): ** ERROR ** (core dumped to file: "/var/lib/ejabberd/MnesiaCore.ejabberd@MYHOST_...")
 ** FATAL ** mnesia_monitor crashed: {badarg,
                                      [{ets,lookup,
                                        [mnesia_decision,
                                         'ejabberdctl@MYHOST']},
                                       {mnesia_recover,has_mnesia_down,1},
                                       {mnesia_monitor,handle_info,2},
                                       {gen_server,handle_msg,5},
                                       {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]} state: {state,
                                                                              <0.65.0>,
                                                                              [],
                                                                              [],
                                                                              true,
                                                                              [],
                                                                              undefined,
                                                                              []}

=ERROR REPORT====
Mnesia('ejabberd@MYHOST'): ** WARNING ** Mnesia is overloaded: {dump_log,
                                                                           time_threshold}

=CRASH REPORT====
  crasher:
    initial call: ejabberd_listener:init/3
    pid: <0.366.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {timeout,
                        {gen_server,call,
                            [<0.682.0>,{become_controller,<0.685.0>}]}}
      in function  gen_server:call/2
      in call from ejabberd_listener:accept/3
    ancestors: [ejabberd_listeners,ejabberd_sup,<0.39.0>]
    messages: [{#Ref<0.0.0.11304>,ok}]
    links: [#Port<0.2761>,<0.274.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: false
    status: running
    heap_size: 2584
    stack_size: 24
    reductions: 20938
  neighbours:
```

Comment: The "slogan" says that the `kernel` application was shut down, but doesn't tell us why.  Are there any crash reports in `ejabberd.log` or `sasl.log`? (At least that was what the log files were called when I last ran ejabberd.)

Comment: @legoscia: Thank you! I've added details from that log to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `erl_crash.dump` file contains the states of almost everything in the moment when the Erlang VM crashed. There's a tool for analyzing it, just:

1. Start an Erlang shell and start the webtool:

   ```
   somebody@somehost> erl
   Erlang R15B02 (erts-5.9.2) [source] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]

   Eshell V5.9.2  (abort with ^G)
   1> webtool:start().
   WebTool is available at http://localhost:8888/
   Or  http://127.0.0.1:8888/
   {ok,<0.35.0>}
   2>
   ```
2. Navigate to the address given above with your browser, and click *WebTool* -> *Start Tools* -> *CrashDumpViewer* -> *Start*, then *CrashDumpViewer* -> *Load Crashdump*.
3. Look for the *Slogan* in *General Information*. It's the summarized reason of crashing.
4. Look for processes with a state other than *Waiting*. Those processes are doing something while the Erlang VM crashed, they are probably the sources.

Comment: Thank you! `webtool:start().` works and it says that it is now available. But in the browser, I can't access `MY_IP:8888`. Anyway, ejabberd is the only Erlang software I'm running, so this *must* be the source.

Comment: The *webtool* only binds to the loopback IP 127.0.0.1, so one can't access it on a remote machine. Maybe move the dump file to you local machine and analyze it?

Comment: And as I wrote *processes*, I meant *Erlang processes*, which run in the Erlang VM, not *system processes* as can be seen in the `ps` command. Sorry for the confusion :P

Comment: Thanks, that was the reason, I was trying to connect to a remote machine. Unfortunately, can't run it on my local machine. But thanks for the description of the Erlang log debugging. Will be helpful to others with a similar problem, at least.

Answer (score 2):

You can only execute ejabberdctl once. Executing it twice from your PHP will generate conflict in node naming and the crash you see.

Do not use ejabberdctl from code, but rely on API.

Comment: Thank you very much! Calls to ejabberdctl in high frequency are no problem, I guess, but only concurrent calls are not possible, right? So would aquiring a lock via PHP also work? And there's no built-in API, right? I think you're refering to something like the following? https://github.com/jadahl/mod_restful

Answer (score 0):

Are they any chances that you are string ejabberd twice?

Comment: Starting it twice? I don't think so, as I don't start it manually. I use use it with my client libraries anc execute calls to `ejabberdctl` via PHP, but that could happen very often and fast in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an erlang.log log file? If so, you should find good info in there about a crash.

Comment: Yes, I had added the content of that logfile in the question above. I can't see the cause for the problem, though. It could only be the captcha module ...

Comment: Hmm... I'm only seeing the crash log and ejabberd.log. There should be an erlang.log which should give you more info on this.

Comment: Ah, sorry, so many logfiles ... In `/var/log/ejabberd/`, there was a file `erlang.log`. I've added the contents to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, the erlang.log file gets overwritten when you restart. Next time it crashes, take a look at the file (or move it) before restarting ejabberd.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I've added a new excerpt from that file to the question above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ssh port forwarding to export webtool to your local machine, where you can point a browser at it.  Exposing it to the whole internet would probably be a bad security error.